# Python print isn't using __repr__, __unicode__ or __str__ for unicode subclass?

Tags: python, class, unicode, subclass, derived-class

Python print isn't using `__repr__`, `__unicode__` or `__str__` for my unicode subclass when printing. Any clues as to what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

Using Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Oct 13 2009, 14:11:59)

```
>>> class MyUni(unicode):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "__repr__"
...     def __unicode__(self):
...         return unicode("__unicode__")
...     def __str__(self):
...         return str("__str__")
...      
>>> s = MyUni("HI")
>>> s
'__repr__'
>>> print s
'HI'
```

I'm not sure if this is an accurate approximation of the above, but just for comparison:

```
>>> class MyUni(object):
...     def __new__(cls, s):
...         return super(MyUni, cls).__new__(cls)
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "__repr__"
...     def __unicode__(self):
...         return unicode("__unicode__")
...     def __str__(self):
...         return str("__str__")
...
>>> s = MyUni("HI")
>>> s
'__repr__'
>>> print s
'__str__'
```

[EDITED...]
It sounds like the best way to get a string object that isinstance(instance, basestring) and offers control over unicode return values, and with a unicode repr is...

```
>>> class UserUnicode(str):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "u'%s'" % super(UserUnicode, self).__str__()
...     def __str__(self):
...         return super(UserUnicode, self).__str__()
...     def __unicode__(self):
...         return unicode(super(UserUnicode, self).__str__())
...
>>> s = UserUnicode("HI")
>>> s
u'HI'
>>> print s
'HI'
>>> len(s)
2
```

The **_*str*_** and **_*repr*_** above add nothing to this example but the idea is to show a pattern explicitly, to be extended as needed.

Just to prove that this pattern grants control:

```
>>> class UserUnicode(str):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "u'%s'" % "__repr__"
...     def __str__(self):
...         return "__str__"
...     def __unicode__(self):
...         return unicode("__unicode__")
... 
>>> s = UserUnicode("HI")
>>> s
u'__repr__'
>>> print s
'__str__'
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Is your code really indented like the first example?

Comment: I had to guess as to what your question is. If I got it wrong, please do update your post to *include an actual, clear question*.

Comment: Though this is a nice gotcha, I would like to ask why in h*** you would like to subclass str or unicode? I mean, the data will be immutable, so it the resulting object will be quite useless.

Comment: I added some more after [Edited...]. Feels gross but I don't think it breaks any Pythonic expectations. repr is a string representation that could be used to build a unicode object if needed, right?

Comment: @Kay: Not useless at all. I've used it to create a name-convention object model for a 3D graphics software package. Basically making a name a special type of string that encapsulates utilities for working with the convention but can still be passed to the native API transparently. The 3D app is mostly unicode so I was trying to be consistent. However, in the case of this thread, I am wrapping an API object and I want the return value of my class to be dynamic, so it only mimics a true string - just has to pass isinstance(instance, basestring)...don't ask...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `print` doesn't respect `__str__` on `unicode` subclasses.

From [`PyFile_WriteObject`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2145593d108d/Objects/fileobject.c), used by `print`:

```
int
PyFile_WriteObject(PyObject *v, PyObject *f, int flags)
{
...
        if ((flags & Py_PRINT_RAW) &&
    PyUnicode_Check(v) && enc != Py_None) {
    char *cenc = PyString_AS_STRING(enc);
    char *errors = fobj->f_errors == Py_None ? 
      "strict" : PyString_AS_STRING(fobj->f_errors);
    value = PyUnicode_AsEncodedString(v, cenc, errors);
    if (value == NULL)
        return -1;
```

`PyUnicode_Check(v)` returns true if `v`'s type is `unicode` *or a subclass*. This code therefore writes unicode objects directly, without consulting `__str__`.

Note that subclassing `str` and overriding `__str__` works as expected:

```
>>> class mystr(str):
...     def __str__(self): return "str"
...     def __repr__(self): return "repr"
... 
>>> print mystr()
str
```

as does calling `str` or `unicode` explicitly:

```
>>> class myuni(unicode):
...     def __str__(self): return "str"
...     def __repr__(self): return "repr"
...     def __unicode__(self): return "unicode"
... 
>>> print myuni()

>>> str(myuni())
'str'
>>> unicode(myuni())
u'unicode'
```

I believe this could be construed as a bug in Python as currently implemented.

Answer (score 6):

You are subclassing `unicode`.

It'll never call `__unicode__` because it *already is* unicode. What happens here instead is that the object is *encoded* to the `stdout` encoding:

```
>>> s.encode('utf8')
'HI'
```

except that it'll use direct C calls instead of the `.encode()` method. This is the default behaviour for `print` for unicode objects.

The `print` statement calls [`PyFile_WriteObject`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#l2543), which in turn calls [`PyUnicode_AsEncodedString`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/unicodeobject.c#l1291) when handling a `unicode` object. The latter then defers to *an* encoding function for the current encoding, and these use the [Unicode C macros](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Include/unicodeobject.h#l431) to access the data structures directly. You cannot intercept this from Python.

What you are looking for is an `__encode__` hook, I guess. Since this is already a `unicode` subclass, `print` needs only to encode, not to convert it to `unicode` *again*, nor can it convert it to string without encoding it explicitly. You'd have to take this up with the Python core developers, to see if an `__encode__` makes sense.

Comment: Since it doesn't do this for `str` subclasses, I think this is a Python bug. See my answer.

Comment: @nneonneo: not sure that I agree just yet. :-)

Comment: Hm, why would it not be a bug? Treatment of `str` and `unicode` should be relatively uniform in Python 2.7.

Comment: @nneonneo: Turning `unicode` into a `str` for printing requires encoding. Turning anything else into a string requires calling `__str__`. Note the second example in the OP post; printing a custom object uses `__str__`, **not** `__unicode__`.

Comment: Fine for `unicode` itself, but makes less sense for `unicode` subclasses. Feels like the code should call `PyUnicode_CheckExact`.

Comment: @nneonneo: If this is a real usecase (which I doubt), there should be some kind of `__encode__` hook instead.

Comment: I feel it is a bug because I should be able to override it. If the base class is bypassing the expected behavior, it feels like something should be exposed to account for subclass overrides.

Comment: @Rafe: but `__unicode__` is for converting something *to* unicode. `unicode(yourtype)` certainly will call it. But `print` is not converting, it is *encoding* instead. You may want to override the encoding behaviour, but there currently is no hook for that. You'd have to discuss that on the Python dev or ideas list instead, as a new feature.

Comment: @Martijn: That makes sense, but isn't the issue that the unicode sub-class is ignoring __str__ when printing? That is where it feels like a bug to me. If it didn't ignore __str__ I'd be happy. Am I missing your point still?

Comment: @Rafe: So what encoding should `__str__` use then? You have *no way* of telling that method what encoding to use...