# Print is blocking forever when printing unicode subclass instance from IDLE

Tags: python, unicode, python-idle

When executing the following lines with an IDLE prompt, the execution is blocking forever at the last line.

```
>>> class Foo(unicode):
        pass

>>> foo = Foo('bar')
>>> print str(foo)     # prints bar
>>> print repr(foo)    # prints u'bar'
>>> print foo          # blocks forever!!
```

This is weird because it is working as expected when executed from python.exe console. This might be related with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687676/python-print-isnt-using-repr-unicode-or-str-for-unicode-subclass), but I am not sure.
I am using python 2.7.5 32-bit with Windows 7 x64.
Can someone explain me what is happening here? Thank you!

EDIT: Some more tests...

If I save the class `Foo(unicode): pass` in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\mymodule.py

Now IDLE does not block with the following code:

```
>>> from mymodule import Foo
>>> print Foo('bar') # prints bar like expected.
```

Comment: When you say blocks forever, you mean you do not get another `>>>` prompt, and nothing prints?

Comment: nothing prints, I don't get another >>> prompt and I can't stop it using ctrl-C!! The only way to end it is to close IDLE.

Comment: Very interesting!  Same happens to me using 2.7.5 on 32-bit Windows Vista.

Comment: I've tested it with a clean installation of python 2.7 on a Window VM and I got the same result!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FYI, after reproducing, I opened a bug report for you, here:

http://bugs.python.org/issue19481

Comment: Thank you, I will keep investigating on my side!